# Unable to link openssl libraries to CLion C program on windows with cygwin

Tags: c, openssl, cygwin, clion

I'm new to C programming, and I wanted to start a project for learning purposes.
I am trying to open an ssl socket in C with clion on windows using cygwin.
For the code I've been using this tutorial:
https://aticleworld.com/ssl-server-client-using-openssl-in-c/

I've installed cygwin with those libs: make, gdb, gcc-g++, libssl-dev

I don't see any compliation errors in the editor, but I can't run thr project.
When I try to run it I get many errors of `undefined` during the linking phase:

```
undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
```

and many more like it.

So I updated m cmake file to look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(ssl_example C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
include_directories(/usr/include/openssl/)
link_libraries(openssl)
add_executable(ssl_example main.c)
```

and now I get this error-

```
FAILED: ssl_example.exe 
: && /usr/bin/gcc.exe -g -Wl,--enable-auto-import CMakeFiles/ssl_example.dir/main.c.o -o ssl_example.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libssl_example.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lopenssl  -lcrypto && :
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenssl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**EDIT:**

```
this is how my cmake file looks like:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(ssl_example C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
include_directories(/usr/include/openssl/)
link_libraries(ssl)
link_libraries(crypto)
link_libraries(openssl)
add_executable(ssl_example main.c)
```

I still get the same error `cannot find -lopenssl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OPENSSL_init_crypto` belongs to `libcrypto`

```
$ cd /usr/lib

$ grep OPENSSL_init_crypto  *.dll.a
grep: libcrypto.dll.a: binary file matches

$ nm libcrypto.dll.a |grep " T " |grep OPENSSL_init
0000000000000000 T OPENSSL_init_crypto
0000000000000000 T OPENSSL_init
```

while the other two to `libssl`

```
$ grep OPENSSL_init_ssl  *.dll.a
grep: libssl.dll.a: binary file matches

$ nm libssl.dll.a |grep " T " |grep OPENSSL_init_ssl
0000000000000000 T OPENSSL_init_ssl

$ grep SSL_CTX_new *.dll.a
grep: libQtNetwork.dll.a: binary file matches
grep: libssl.dll.a: binary file matches

nm libssl.dll.a |grep " T " |grep SSL_CTX_new
0000000000000000 T SSL_CTX_new
```

so you need to link versus both `libssl` and `libcrypto`

Comment: I edited my question with my current cmake file. I still get the same error

Comment: remove `link_libraries(openssl)`. Already Pedro Perez told you so

Answer (score 1):

The library you must link to is called "libssl" not "openssl". In the linking must appear as '-lssl', not '-lopenssl'

Comment: I tried to replace `link_libraries(openssl)` with `link_libraries(ssl)` and I got the same error and also when I tried `link_libraries(libssl)` I still got the same error

Comment: the error can not be exactly the same. Have you re-run cmake ?

Comment: @matzeri when I use `link_libraries(ssl)` only, I get the `undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'` errors. when I use both `link_libraries(openssl)` and `link_libraries(ssl)` then I get the same `cannot find -lopenssl` error

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your cygwin runtime does not have openssl libraries installed. Use the cygwin setup to install it.

1. Open cygwin setup
2. In select packages panel, enter 'libssl' in the search box.
3. On the libssl-devel, click the dropdown menu, select the version you want.
4. After finishing installing, you can check the libraries are installed. Open cygwin bash terminal, enter 'ls /usr/lib', you should see libcrypto.dll.a and libssl.dll.a

[cygwin setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8f3V.png)